# How do I interrupt/kill a hung thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to figure out how threading works in Java. I want to understand how I can interrupt a thread which was created to run another terminal process. I have the following threads:

- **main thread**
- **swing thread** - manages the GUI
- **terminal thread** - runs the terminal process

The terminal process needs to feed its output to the input stream of the terminal thread. I've managed to do this via a while loop. However, doing so will actually hang the thread if the terminal process is stuck (eg waiting for user input).

My question is two fold:

1. How do I interrupt the terminal thread? (see my code below)
2. If I close my application via main and the swing thread, will this close the terminal thread? I've been closing my application this way... will the ghost thread keep running? If so, how do I exorcise it?

**Below code is the a runnable implementation to run the thread which in turns run the terminal process:**

```
public void run(){
    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("Enter a terminal process that hangs here");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

    Process pr;
    try {
        pr = pb.start();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            pr.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("ok!");
        in.close();
        //System.exit(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**I was expecting for *!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()* to stop the loop and provide the interrupt. However, it won't interrupt when I called an interrupt via the below code:**

```
JButton btnKillThreads = new JButton("Kill Threads");
btnKillThreads.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        for (Thread thread : threads){
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    }
});
```

**And here is the code that created the thread for completeness:**

```
JButton btnStartConversion = new JButton("Start Thread");
btnStartConversion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Runnable rt = new Thread1();
        Thread t = new Thread(rt);
        t.start();
        threads.add(t);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have a good start. The only issue is that `Thread.interrupt()` won't stop the process. If the thread is blocked by `in.readLine()`, it won't exit until the process produced the output and the thread got a chance to check `isInterrupted()`.

If you want to stop the process, in addition to calling `Thread.interrupt()` you need to call `Process.destroy()`:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

   private Process pr; 

   public void run() {

      // ...

      pr = pb.start();
   }

   public shutdown() {
      pr.destroy();
      interrupt();
   }
}
```

Instead of registering the thread in the list you'll need to register your `MyRunnable` and call `shutdown()` on it.

As for thread's behavior on `System.exit()`, all threads will be destroyed. However, using `System.exit()` is considered bad form because it terminates the application without giving threads a chance to shutdown gracefully. A sound engineering practice is to think through the graceful shutdown and use `System.exit()` only as a last resort.

Comment: Thank you. This did the trick! Can you please advise on the second part of the question? If I exit the program without closing the threads, will they keep running? Let's assume I exit with system.Exit(0).

Comment: I've added an explanation.

Comment: Thank you. I Would upvote, but I don't have enough reps yet. I will revisit when I Do. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition in your while loop to:

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```